# how to add a plusonebutton or any other element before fragment list_content

Tags: android, android-layout

how to add a plusonebutton or any other element before fragment list_content
this is what i tried, but the button is over the list not before it!

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sl"
    android:name="dev.dev.dev.SListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".SActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"  >

<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
  xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
  android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  plus:size="standard"
  plus:annotation="inline" />

</fragment>
```

here is a snapshot of the above
[image]

I need the google+ plus button above the list not over it like this:

[image]

Comment: What? I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Emmanuel check the snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SActivity" >

<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
  xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
  android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
  plus:size="standard"
  plus:annotation="inline" />

<fragment

    android:id="@+id/sl"
    android:name="dev.dev.dev.SListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".SActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```